# Search item in an array using PHP

Tags: php

I want to search an item like "January" or "February" in an array that looks like this

```
 Array
(
   [0] => January

   [1] => February

   [2] => March

   [3] => April

)
```

This what I have tried so far. But not working.

```
if ( in_array("January", $date_array) ) {
        echo "Found item in Array";
} else {
        echo "Didn't find item in Array";
}
```

result:

```
Didn't find item in Array
```

This is the result of var_dump()

```
 array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(9) "January
  "
  [1]=>
  string(10) "February
  "
  [2]=>
  string(7) "March
  "
  [3]=>
  string(7) "April
  "  
  }
```

Comment: `var_dump` your array. Your code works fine https://3v4l.org/rpmuU So, maybe your array element is not `'January'`, or maybe `'January '` (with space).

Comment: Check your arrayname

Comment: `var_dump` shows that January has __9__ symbols. But in word `January` - 7. So, there are some unprinted symbols in it. Oh, it's a __line break__.

Answer (score 2):

Don't know, where line breaks are coming from, but you can remove them, for example, with [`array_map`](https://www.php.net/array_map):

```
$date_array = array_map('trim', $date_array);
// and then use `in_array`
```